# Server Request URI WildCard Magento

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, request

I'm currently using the following code to generate an active state on links:
`<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/styles/bracelets.html/"):?>`

Followed by an else if statement.
How would I add a wild card so that the path above includes all pages with a path of: /styles/bracelets.html?p=2, /styles/bracelets.html?p=3 etc.

Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: Welcome to SO, hope you enjoy your time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) in this case:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/styles/bracelets.html/') === 0):
```

This basically checks to make sure `/styles/bracelets.html/` is at the beginning of the request URI and will also pass if there is additional content trailing the `/` on the end.  `strpos` will return false if the need is not found in haystack, or 0 if it is found at the beginning of the haystack hence the need for `===`.

[preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match) would also work, but strpos does the trick in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I am enjoying my time here.

Comment: It would replace what you have in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found somewhat cleaner approach:

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/desired_page_name.php')
```

The `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` returns the current script's path but omits possible $_GET concatenations.

i.e if  `www.example.com/page.php?variable=value` is entered, then `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` would contain only `/page.php` part.